# React&TS_HTMLTableSectionElement and currentIndex

Tags: reactjs, typescript, events

I have handler function which I use on the headers of the table:

```
  const sort = (event: MouseEventHandler<HTMLTableSectionElement>) => {
    const column = event.target.currentIndex;
    ...
  };

...

return (
    <>
      <table>
        <thead onClick={sort}>...
```

where the line `const column = event.target.currentIndex;` give me an error:

> Property 'target' does not exist on type 'MouseEventHandler'.ts(2339)

I've tried to specify the type explicitly like: `const column = (event.target as HTMLTableCellElement).currentIndex;` and other HTMLTable variations, but have the same error.

Then I've tried to change type of the event:

```
const sort = (event: Event) => {
    const column = (event.target as HTMLTableCellElement).currentIndex;
```

but then there is another error:

> Property 'currentIndex' does not exist on type 'HTMLTableCellElement'.ts(2339)

How can I solve this issue?